# Angular best practices using bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I am new to learning Angular and I would like to ask some questions about good practices when working with bootstrap for responsive web design.

Suppose that I want to re-create a website that uses bootstrap but this time I want to make it using angular too. Would it be a good practice if I made each row/column a seperate component in order to achieve maximum abstraction? Or is it the exact opposite of what I said (many components on an Angular app is not optimal).

What would be better in a situation that we have nested bootstrap rows/columns?

Eg.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
          <img src="image.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
          <span>Dummy Text </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
          <span> Dummy Text 2 </span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
              <span> Dummy Text 3 </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
              <span> Dummy Text 4 </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Should every row be a seperate component?
I hope my question is clear enough for you to understand.

Comment: This is actually a strategy that you have to decide on. For example, if dummy text is to be used only on this page, you don't need to make it a separate component. If you need to use it in multiple places, it would be much better to have a component.